# Use wildcard in tox command

Tags: linux, bash, wildcard, tox

For different reasons I have to do pip install as a command in my tox.ini (I do `skipsdist=True` so tox will not install my dependencies for me, but I still need some of them installed into the virtual environment).

The problem is that I have a local dependency stored as a tarball, that has its version in its filename, such as `my-module-1.0.tar.gz`. I therefore need to use a wildcard in my command, such as

```
pip install my-module-*.tar.gz
```

but tox does not seem to support bash semantics in this sense, as I get the error

```
Requirement 'my-module-*.tar.gz' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
```

I have tried putting quotes around the filename as well as escaping the asterisk, without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which subdirectory do you run that command? Is that tarball found in the same subdirectory where you run pip?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not a tox user, but it looks like tox does not use a shell to execute commands. You could try calling a shell explicitly, e.g.:

```
/bin/bash -c 'pip install my-module-*.tar.gz'
```

Comment: glad I could help :)